# Installing One Plugin on a Few Blogs on a MultiSite

Tags: multisite

I would like to install a plugin on 3 out of the 20 blogs I have going on my MutliSite WP 3.0. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugins folder is shared. You can install one copy of the plugin and *activate* it on three blogs and not the others.

If you don;t want the others to be aware of the plugin's existence... you'll have to use another plugin to exclude it.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-multisite-plugins/
or

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-plugins/